# No free disk space while installing Fedora 15

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I am on a Windows 7 system trying to install Fedora 15 Linux.

I am using Fedora 15 live image which I burned onto a DVD and booted. According to instructions I've found in a tutorial I go into the system tools and choose install to hard drive. I have previously shrunk the Windows system drive to free up approx 200 GB of unallocated space. I did this through:

> Control Panel → Administrative tools → Computer management → Windows Disk Manager

While I try to install Fedora on the harddrive I run into two problems:

1. I can't install it because it says "no free space available to create partition".

   It doesn't matter if I choose the auto partition option or the custom partition option. Choosing the custom partitioning option I don't know which partitions I need to create. Terminology such as LVM and PV are all new to me.
2. After a random interval I am forced to re-login as a live user which kills the installation program and forces me to restart the installation process.

Does anyone know how to solve these problems?

Comment: I can't help you, but you'd better post it into the Linux QA...

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you actually shrunk the partition effectively? check again in Windows disk management. You may be better off using a bootable tool like [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), because editing the partition table while an OS is booted from it is always limited.